# SQL Server 2022 evaluates statement after condition that is false

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Code to replicate in SQL Server 2022 v16.0.4095.4:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnInner] 
    (@id uniqueidentifier, @date datetime) 
RETURNS integer 
AS
BEGIN
    IF @id IS NULL
       RETURN CAST('null @id' AS int);

    IF @date IS NULL
       RETURN CAST('null @date' AS int);

    RETURN 1;
END
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnOuter] 
    (@id uniqueidentifier) 
RETURNS varchar(10) 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @case integer, @test int, @ret varchar(10);
    
    SELECT @case = 2, @test = NULL, @ret = 'None';

    IF @case = 1
        SET @test = dbo.fnInner(@id, NULL);
    ELSE IF @case = 2
        SET @ret = 'Two';
    ELSE IF @test IS NULL
        SET @ret = 'Null';

    RETURN @ret
END
GO

SELECT dbo.fnOuter(NEWID());
```

Expected result: 'Two'

Actual result:

> Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'null @date' to data type int

In SQL Server 2008 (v10.50.4042.0):

Expected Result: 'Two'

Actual Result: 'Two'

Comment: Why are you surprised by this error? `'null @id'` is *not* a valid `int`. The problem is the same as your [prior question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77762144/is-this-sql-server-function-compiling-incorrectly), inlining not doing what you want, combined with a questionable solution.

Comment: @ThomA because case var <> 1 so I wouldn't expect fnInner to be evaluated.  Also, the prior question was closed because it was overly complicated and not clear.  This question should not be closed for those reasons.

Comment: You expect wrong, the function is being inlined.

Comment: @ThomA It was being inlined in 2008 too, correct?

Comment: No, inlining didn't exist on scalar functions in 2008.

Comment: @ThomA you have answered my question.  Thank you.  Btw, when did they start inlining like that?

Comment: Inlining can be controlled with a database-scoped configuration if it's a problem for you but it would be better to fix the actual code with `TRY_CONVERT` or `TRY_CAST`.

Comment: Thanks @DanGuzman, we are patching the old code to not use that workaround to throw an error message from a function anymore.

Comment: @ThomA - 2019 not 2016

Comment: Must have hit the wrong key and not noticed, thanks @MartinSmith .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the following article: [Scalar UDF Inlining](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/user-defined-functions/scalar-udf-inlining?view=sql-server-ver16).

Near the end there is a small notice that says: *"Certain warnings in statements inside the UDF (such as divide by zero etc.) which might have been hidden earlier, might show up due to inlining."*

In the same article you can find several ways to disable inlining, for the entire database or only for some UDF or statement, so you can get the expected results.

However, I think you should try reporting this as a bug (see [SQL Server help and feedback](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/sql-server-get-help?view=sql-server-ver15) for several ways to do this). Maybe Microsoft will fix this behavior in a later version. See [KB4538581](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/topic/kb4538581-fix-scalar-udf-inlining-issues-in-sql-server-2022-and-2019-f52d3759-a8b7-a107-1ab9-7fbee264dd5d) to find out other weird behaviors that appeared as a result of inlining in the initial versions of SQL Server 2019 and were fixed in later versions of SQL Server 2019 or SQL Server 2022.

It is interesting to note that the problem is not happening in SQL Server 2019 GDR (version 15.0.2104.1), but it appears in SQL Server 2019 CU22 (version 15.0.4326.1), so this can be categorised as a regression.

Comment: There were many changes made to scalar UDF inlining over the course of the CUs.  It may not be inlining in the earlier CUs or GDR train.  But in any case it's not a regression because the CU22 behavior is correct.

Comment: What is interesting from [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/GVcNxhxa) is that the query `SELECT * FROM sys.sql_modules` shows that `fnOuter()` has `is_inlineable=true`, but `fnInner()` has `is_inlineable=false`. Perhaps the inlining of `fnOuter()` is drilling too deep. If `fnOuter()` is modified so that it is no longer inlineable, the error no longer occurs. Adding `WITH INLINE = OFF` to `fnInner()` does not resolve the issue, but adding it to `fnOuter()` does.

Comment: @TN Very useful info from you - Thanks.  When I comment out `ELSE IF @test IS NULL set @ret = 'Null'` in fnOuter, then `select dbo.fnOuter(newid())` succeeds with result 'Two'.  But sql_modules still shows fnOuter with is_inlineable = 1.  Does this indicate the inline version with the error is evaluating fnInner at runtime with a null argument to preemptively determine the value of `@test`?

Comment: @RazvanSocol Thanks for your accepted answer.  I'm not sure if this behavior is a bug or not.  David Browne indicates this CU22 behavior is correct.  Yet, it doesn't seem correct to me that the inline function is evaluating fnInner with a null argument when the not-inlined function would not.

Comment: @RJBreneman - Back in my C/C++ days, I recall that compiler optimizations had to follow the "as-if rule", meaning the optimization could not change the observable behavior. On facet of this is that if a constant expression threw an error, it could just be replaced with a statement that threw the error when executed, but this would not be a compile time error. The statement would not throw if executed. (I wish I had a good reference for this, but I cant find one right now.) I do not know if Microsoft has the intent to follow the same rule for SQL Server. If they do, I would consider this a bug.

Comment: ...The fact that removing the seemingly unrelated line of code `ELSE IF @test IS NULL set @ret = 'Null'` changes the behavior, seems to indicate that logic to throw an error only if executed is present in some cases. I played around with [this fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/mzLEcSW_) and also confirms deferred error behaviors, even with inlineable functions.

Comment: Bug Report - The code sample here demonstrates that changing only 'WITH INLINE = ON/OFF' changes the runtime behavior.
[BUG - inline function runtime behavior is different than non-inline behavior with same code and same inputs.](https://feedback.azure.com/d365community/idea/d6470086-0aaf-ee11-92bc-0022484c4141)